# Ceiling Fan with Recessed Lights

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, recessed-lighting

This is for U.S. based electrical in a house built in 2001.

Currently I have a ceiling fan w/light on a 14/2 NM-B run to a single-pole light switch. When the switch is turned off, neither the fan nor light turn on. If switch is turned on, the light or fan can be activated based off pull chains on fan.

I want to add 4 recessed lights off the ceiling fan (which I will be replacing with a remote controlled fan), except I need the lights controlled by the switch, and the fan to be always on (as it will be controlled by the remote control, and not the switch).

I believe I need to pull 14/3 NM-B wire in place of the 14/2 to make this work. Please confirm. See diagram for proposed solution.

[image: Wiring Diagram]

FYI: Wire B is going to a different room, Wire C is the wire I would switch out with 14/3.

Also, I left out Ground from the diagram to make it cleaner, I would obviously ground everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this right-on-the-money, save for one thing.  I'd pull a 14/*4* instead of the 14/3 -- that way, if you want to have two separate switched hots at the fan location as well as a switched hot for the cans, you can do that.  Copper is cheap compared to the hassle of re-pulling wires!

Comment: 14/3 is able to switch two hots... 14/4 would just give an additional but unnecessary neutral.

Comment: I meant atop the existing switched hot for the cans :)

Comment: Oh, so 3 switch loops ?

Comment: @Kris 14/4 has `white black red blue` good for 3 switched hots.  (Or 2 switched and an unswitched.  Or 3-phase.) 14/2/2 has `black red and 2 whites`, intended for 2 complete circuits.   14/2/2 is the universal donor since you can re-mark one of the whites.

Comment: @Harper 14/2/2 is actually more common at the DIY local store.. 14/4 i've only seen through electrical warehouses.